# Batch rename Mesh and Material data to object name with specific prefix and suffix

Tags: python, objects, linked-data

I am batch processing asset files of which the scene contains just 4 objects.
Each of these objects and its associated data currently have a generic name.

1. The mesh should be named *"VEG_"* + [Object name]

Note: the mesh data is linked across the object

For the object name, I want to:

3. Apply a prefix *"VEG_"*
4. Apply a suffix for each of the seasons *"_Spring", "_Summer", "_Winter", "_Autumn"*, so one for each object

The material name needs to correspond to the object's initial name and receive prefixes.

5. Apply the prefix "VEG_[Object name]"
6. Apply the suffix *"_Spring", "_Summer", "_Winter", "_Autumn"*

Can I rename the objects through python?
See an example below of the current naming scheme and the desired scheme.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How computer know which object use "_Spring", which one use "_Summer" ?

Comment: The first object is [object name], which could be "_Spring". The second is [object name].001, which would use "_Summer", the third is [object name].002, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
# suppose only 4 objects
import bpy

# generator
gen = (s for s in ["_Spring", "_Summer", "_Winter", "_Autumn"])

bpy.data.objects[0].name = bpy.data.objects[0].name + ".000"

for i, oj in enumerate(bpy.data.objects):
    s = next(gen)
    name = oj.name[: -4]
    oj.name = f"VEG_{name}{s}"
    oj.data.name = oj.name
    if oj.material_slots[0].material:
        mat_name = oj.material_slots[0].material.name
        oj.material_slots[0].material.name = f"VEG_{name}_{mat_name}{s}"
    if oj.material_slots[1].material:
        mat_name = oj.material_slots[1].material.name
        oj.material_slots[1].material.name = f"VEG_{name}.{mat_name}{s}"
```

reference of f-strings:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/

reference of generator:
https://python-course.eu/advanced-python/generators-iterators.php

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out tomorrow. Do you happen to know what I could do to not hardcode "_leaf" and "_trunk"? Some materials have additional slots and therefore different names. Can I process them in a similar way, by adding the suffix to the existing object name, which is treated as a variable in itself?

Comment: I update a new one which will follow your material name.