# Material slot renaming - Only rename slot if it is in use?

Tags: python, materials, scripting

I want to rename my Material slots for a series of objects.
In [another question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261379/batch-rename-mesh-and-material-data-to-object-name-with-specific-prefix-and-suff/261405#261405), someone suggested that I use this code:

```
gen = (s for s in ["_Spring", "_Summer", "_Winter", "_Autumn"])
 
bpy.data.objects[0].name = bpy.data.objects[0].name + ".000"
 
for oj in bpy.data.objects:
    s = next(gen)
    name = oj.name[: -4]
    oj.name = f"{name}{s}"
    oj.data.name = oj.name
    oj.material_slots[0].material.name = f"{name}_leaf{s}"
    oj.material_slots[1].material.name = f"{name}_trunk{s}"
```

Some objects that I need to process have a third slot called "Leaf_2". How could I add a check which, if the slot exists renames the slot similar to how slot 0 and 1 are renamed? And if it there is no such slot, don't modify nor create one. How could that be achieved?

Comment: I've modified your question to use StackExchange formatting for the script.  If you start with a line consisting of three back-tick characters and end with another one, everything in between is treated as source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Python idiom for this:

```
if thing:
    do something
```

That means 'if this thing has a value other than `None` then do something'.

Applying this to material slots in your code you would get

```py
if oj.material_slots[2].material:
  oj.material_slots[2].material.name = f"{name}_leaf_2{s}'
```

By the way, as an aside, *"Code is read far more often than it is written."*  That being true, please use longer variable names for readability.  Also, if you are going to use short names, be aware that Blender Python has some ad-hoc conventions, such as using `obj` as the abbreviation for an `object`.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks a lot! That's something I will definitely keep in mind, the cleaner the code the easier it is to manage.